# Adding context to django admin changelist_view

Tags: django

I'm trying to add some context to a Django admin view when the change list is displayed.

I have this class

```
class LeadStatSummaryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'admin/stats/leadstatsummary/change_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        query=Q()
        if 'from_date' in request.GET:
            from_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.GET['from_date'], '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            to_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.GET['to_date'], '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            query = Q(date_of_lead__gte=from_date, date_of_lead__lte=to_date)

        return qs.filter(query)

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        response = super().changelist_view(
            request,
            extra_context=extra_context,)

        qs = self.get_queryset(request)

        response.context_data['date_form'] = DateForm(request.GET or None) 
        response.context_data['data'] = qs. \
            values('type_of_lead', 'may_contact_provider', 'type_of_care_care_home', 'type_of_care_home_care', 
                'type_of_care_live_in_care', 'type_of_care_retirement_village') \
            .order_by('type_of_lead', 'type_of_care_care_home', 'type_of_care_home_care', 
                'type_of_care_live_in_care', 'type_of_care_retirement_village','may_contact_provider') \
            .annotate(count=Count('type_of_lead'))

        return response
```

This provides a date form I can use to filter the queryset.  This runs fine when called from the menu (so no date form) but when I enter dates and submit I get this error

> 'HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'context_data'

It is referring to this line of code

```
response.context_data['date_form'] = DateForm(request.GET or None)
```

I do not understand why this should be causing an error and how to fix.  Can you help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone interested I resolved using a template tag instead

```
@register.filter
def get_lead_summary(qs):
    return qs.values('type_of_lead', 'may_contact_provider', 'type_of_care_care_home', 'type_of_care_home_care', 
                'type_of_care_live_in_care', 'type_of_care_retirement_village') \
            .order_by('type_of_lead', 'type_of_care_care_home', 'type_of_care_home_care', 
                'type_of_care_live_in_care', 'type_of_care_retirement_village','may_contact_provider') \
            .annotate(count=Count('type_of_lead'))
```

This is called with, for example, `{% for row in cl.result_list|get_lead_summary %}`